# Why isn't .with_lock working as I expect it to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, activerecord, locking

I would expect the below code to force exclusive access to the code block within, but it isn't. In my test, each thread is able to run the block concurrently.

Assume a Rails environment and user is an activerecord object. Also note that this is a somewhat arbitrary test I wrote in order to resolve a concurrency issue I'm experiencing with web requests.

```
user = User.first
threads = []

3.times do |i|
    threads << Thread.new do
        user.with_lock do
            puts "start: #{i}"
            sleep 1
            puts "stop: #{1}"
        end
    end
end

threads.each(&:join)
```

Expected output:

```
start: 1
stop: 1
start: 2
stop: 2
start: 3
stop: 3
```

Actual output:

```
start: 1
start: 2
start: 3
stop: 1
stop: 2
stop: 3
```

What am I missing? Does rails `.with_lock` not work within standard ruby threads? Or, is this possibly due to my test environment using sqlite3?

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to have been related to sqlite3.

Answer (score 1):

You've evidently figured this out already, but to clarify for others encountering this problem:

Sqlite3 doesn't support row-level locking. Therefore, Arel simply ignores any locks when building the query:

https://github.com/rails/arel/blob/master/lib/arel/visitors/sqlite.rb#L7

Comment: Link has moved: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/arel/visitors/sqlite.rb#L8